# Can I capture a series of images named according to its timestamp

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I am successfully capturing a screen shot every 15 seconds with the command below but I need to correlate the images to where in the video the screen shot is from.

The %d gives me an integer, but  is there a similar variable, filter, or otherwise to include or somehow capture the timestamp of the image in the output file name?

```
c:\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -i c:\files\video.mp4 -vf fps=1/15 c:\images\image_%d.png";
```

Current output is :

```
c:\images\image1.png
c:\images\image2.png
c:\images\image3.png
...
c:\images\image999.png
```

Desired output is *something* like:

```
c:\images\image_00-00-00.png    // Capture at start of video
c:\images\image_00-00-15.png    // Capture at 00:00:15
c:\images\image_00-00-30.png    // Capture at 00:00:30
c:\images\image_00-00-45.png    // Capture at 00:00:45
c:\images\image_00-01-00.png    // Capture at 00:01:00
...
c:\images\image_01-25-15.png    // Last capture
```

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible yet. This seems to be ticket [#1452: image2 to support %t](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1452).

Comment: I thought not, though sifting through old google results, seemed the data was available, and hopefully someone had figured it out.  Thank you.

Comment: If you trust that the outputs are exactly 1/15 apart, then you can script some renaming. Lame, but perhaps an option.

Answer (score 1):

As some people have written, there is probably no option for `ffmpeg` command, that can do what you want. On linux machine I would suggest you to use the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
interval=15 # interval between images in seconds

for ((i=0; i<$1; ++i)); do
timestamp=$(date -d @$((-3600+${i}*${interval})) +%H-%M-%S)
mv image${i}.png image_${timestamp}.png
done

exit 0
```

you can call it in the directory with images as

```
$ script_name NNN
```

where `NNN` is the total number of images (I assume that you start numbering with 0 instead of 1, it is not difficult).

As you can see I rely on the linux command `date`, which is capable of converting seconds into hours.

Since you seem to be on Windows machine, there are a couple of options, how you can use this script.

1. Rewrite it into Windows batch file. There is a [topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us), which discusses how to use command similar to `date` on Windows.
2. Install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) and run the script above from cygwin command line
3. Use standalone [bash coomand line](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) for running the script above.